# Insert widget (Label) into Listbox in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi people is it possible to insert Label widget into Listbox in tkinter instead of some str value and attach to it a scrollbar?

Comment: what have you tried? It is possible to put a listbox into tkinter with a scrollbar, or you can add a dropdown list which will make it a little cleaner.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2MjnqvPx 
Till now i have tried this i try to pass instead of str object labelframe to insert but it does not work. I dont know if there are ways to do it

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation online, No

> The listbox can only contain text items...

for further details on the ListBox: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm

Comment: what is the proper way to create scrollable list of labels in tkinter?

Comment: that is another question, and is properly documented in the link I provided

Comment: @BryanOakley that is what i was searching for. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask me to explain it because I really don't understand it yet, but this should work:

```
import tkinter as tk # python3
root = tk.Tk()
myList = tk.Listbox(root)
myText = "A list item"
myList.insert(tk.END, myText)
myList.pack()
lbl = tk.Label(myList, text=myText, anchor="w", font=("Helvetica", "24"))
lbl.pack(side="top", fill="x", anchor="w")
root.mainloop()
```